# the count of substrings in HTML page with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I need to find and count all the "python" and "c++" words as a substrings in HTML code with module BeautifulSoup. In wikipedia these words are met 1 and 9 times accordingly. Why my code writes 0 and 0?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, urlretrieve

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


resp = urlopen("https://stepik.org/media/attachments/lesson/209717/1.html") 

html = resp.read().decode('utf8') 

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser') 

table = soup.find('table', attrs = {'class' : 'wikitable sortable'})

cnt = 0

for tr in soup.find_all("python"):

    cnt += 1

print(cnt)

cnt1 = 0

for tr in soup.find_all("c++"):

    cnt += 1

print(cnt)
```

Comment: There is no class with the name ```wikitable sortable``` in the HTML

Comment: ok, once I have deleted this string nothing changes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong you need to use string argument to search for any string

```py
    
    # These will only work in case like these <b>Python</b>
    soup.find_all(string="Python")

    # Not in these <b>python</b> or <b>Python is best</b>
```

```py
    #We can use regex to fix that they will work in substring cases 
    
    soup.find_all(string=re.compile("[cC]\+\+")) 
    soup.find_all(string=re.compile("[Pp]ython"))
```

Comment: it writes  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/py3e_source/chapter04/7_5.py", line 9
    for tr in soup.find_all(string=re.compile("[cC]\+\+"):
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You forgot to close  parenthesis for find_all

Comment: Thank you very much! But still it does not find all the C++ includings; only nine... in html there are more

Comment: I think that's because string argument only search inside tags it doesn't search in other parts